# Mains powered mini-pc (18.04) shows battery but none is present

Tags: battery

My Minix Z83-4U runs 18.04.1 LTS fine but for some weird reason in Settings and in the Gnome menu bar it shows that it runs on battery (constant 94% charged). This mini-pc is mains powered and does not contain a battery (other than CMOS battery ofcourse). So its configuration is incorrect.

Power Statistics also contains information of a battery...

Anyone a clue on how to tell this box that it runs an AC mains?

Comment: The system doesn't need to be told it's running on AC, the system knows.

Comment: Ofcourse. But it shouldn't show a battery present if there is none. I blacklisted the axp288_fuel_gauge kernel module and all references to a battery are now gone.